# Round numbers based on ending digit in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula in excel to round my price list.

Last digit of my price ends with

0-1-2 = 9 (Example: if price is $50-$51-$52 will be $49)(subtracts)

3 = 4 (Example: if price is $53 will become $54)(add 1)

4 = 4 (Example: if price is $54 will be the same $54)

5 = 5 (Example: if price is $55 will be the same $55)

6-7-8 = 9 (Example: if price is $56-$57-$58 will be $59)(adds)

9 = 9 (Example: if price is $59 will be the same $59)

My price starts from $8 to $1,106.

Thanks and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a price in cell `P1`:

```
=P1+CHOOSE(MOD(P1,10)+1,-1,-2,-3,1,0,0,3,2,1,0)
```

The `MOD(x, y)` function returns the remainder of `x/y`, so `MOD(x, 10)` gets you the last digit by itself.

The `CHOOSE(i, c1, c2, c3, c4, ... )` function returns the item `ci` based on the given index `i`.

Add one to the result of the `MOD()` function to get an index between 1 and 10, and then use the index values to adjust the price according to your spec.

Comment: Very well written. Didn't know about the choose function.